# Is it possible to use C# interactive mode?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if there is any IDE that allows me to use C# in interactive model like Python?

Comment: it seems like F# http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156303/why-does-f-have-an-interactive-mode-but-not-c

Comment: I use LINQPad. Okay, it's "in context" of the VS project, but it works quite well for a quick REPL. Another option is to "Debug" a project and then use the Interactive Window.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl

Answer (score 5):

The [immediate window in Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f177hahy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is essentially a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REPL).

It's a bit hacky, but you could easily jump in there by creating a console project w/ an empty program:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The program will stop here.
        // Open up the immediate window and play around!
        Debugger.Break();
    }
}
```

You can open the immediate window with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Answer (score 5):

[Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx) (next gen compiler/language services for C# and VB) comes with a C# Interactive window. Unlike the immediate window it doesn't require a debugging context.

There's a CTP available for VS2012, so you can try it.

Disclaimer: I work on Roslyn.

Comment: This is a dramatically better alternative, as the editor in the interactive window is essentially a full featured part of the IDE with syntax highlighting, context sensitive parametter info popups, etc.

Comment: Hi Brian, this is great. Is there any way to see the variables and objects that are in the memory though?

Comment: Intellisense is updated when you create new types/variables, but there's no way to list objects currently in memory.